# issue with Captcha when Google Data Compression Proxy is ON

Tags: android, ajax, google-chrome, proxy

We started receiving user complaints that CAPTCHA code is not working when they are using Android Chrome with Data Compression ON.

We investigated further, and we noticed that we save the captcha into SESSION but that session is not available for the end user. We suspect the session is only valid for the proxy->server.

We don't have SSL, it's a very small website.

Is there some other way to skip this proxy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to skip the Chrome Compression Proxy by adding the following header:

```
Cache-Control: no-transform
```

Comment: It's not working. I don't know why, but Google ignores this directive.

Comment: @Dauren It is mentioned in the [official docs](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/data-compression-for-isps#proxy-connection) so it should be supported. Maybe you should file a [bug](https://chromiumbugs.appspot.com)?